# mean of estimator is the estimator itself

Tags: probability, monte-carlo

I've just started reading up on Monte Carlo methods (sparse background in probability and stats back in undergraduate).

Let $\phi(X)$ be a function under a complex distribution $P(X)$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

The expectation, $\Phi$, to this function $\phi(X)$ is:

$\Phi = E[\phi(X)] = \int d^{N} X P(X) \phi(X)$

Since $P(X)$ is sufficiently complex, an exact method to solving for $\Phi$ is difficult so an approach is to sample from the sufficiently complex distribution $P(X)$ first.

If the sampling is done $R$ times, we have $X^{R}$ so that an estimate to this estimator may be described by

$\hat{\Phi} = \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^{R} \phi(X^{r})$.

**So, the expectation of $\hat{\Phi}$ is $\Phi$**

How should I convince myself of the claim in bold? I could only imagine that this is true in the case where $R$ is extremely large so that the variance of $\hat{\Phi}$ decreases. There appears to be more to this claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-studied and well-known concept in statistical inference.

Suppose you want to estimate a quantity $\phi$, let it be a population parameter of some statistical model with distribution $\mathcal{P}$  (say, the mean)  and suppose we know the true value, the $\Phi$. 
Say you come up with an estimator $\hat\phi$ based on samples from distribution $\mathcal{P}$.

Then, $\hat\phi$ is an unbiased estimator of $\phi \hspace{1pt}$ if
$ \hspace{1pt} \mathbb{E}_{{\mathcal{P}}}\big[\hat\phi\big] = \Phi$.

Relevant links:
[Estimator](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Estimator), [Bias of an estimator](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Bias_of_Estimator), [Unbiased Estimator](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Unbiased_Estimator)

The sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean: [Proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sample_Mean_is_Unbiased_Estimator_of_Population_Mean).
It is also the minimum variance estimator, i.e. the "best" estimator, but that doesn't pertain to this question.

Comment: I've heard of the claim in your answer but for some reason did not relate it to it. Thank you.